# How to use 3 cells to actually complete the test

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Ok, so I did have a quick search but did not find an answer that does what I would like... I have a horrible feeling that it is simple.. :)

I would like a formula in cell D1 that will use cells A1, B1 and C1 to evaluate the test shown in B1. This is for producing questions.

The picture shows the data and results.

[image]

I have tried indirect() with no success and &, ie

```
=A1&B1&C1
```

Comment: Maybe use [this workaround](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-factor-12-secret-evaluate-function) with the evaluate function.

Comment: @BigBen that works, put it as an answer and I will vote for it. :) But thanks, made my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Evaluate method in excel VBA. Note that i'm using `.Value` on the `rng2`. This is because we want to use the displayed value of the cell (in the format in which it appears to the user lookins at the cell) rather than the underlying value that excel stores in the cell (which is what `.value2` gives us).

```
Public Function EEE(rng As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range)
    EEE = Evaluate(rng.Value2 & rng2.Value & rng3.Value2)
End Function
```

Note that there is a method of doing it using only worksheet functions, but it rather complicated compared to the VBA solution. An excellent descriptio of the old `Evaluate()` function and how to use it is given in this [article](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-factor-12-secret-evaluate-function).

Comment: will test this in a bit, but I can see it working as it is similar to the link BigBen provided, however thanks.

Comment: @SolarMike seeing as the article I mentioned is also included in this answer, I'm fine not adding an additional one.

Comment: Cheers to both!

Answer (score 0):

Following formula could be used to evaluate the result of combination of A1, B1, C1

```
 =ISLOGICAL(A1&B1&C1)
```

or

```
 =ISLOGICAL(CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1))
```

Comment: For ISLOGICAL to evaluate to TRUE, you have to have TRUE or FALSE e.g. in a Cell. Even '=ISLOGICAL("TRUE")' evaluates to FALSE. I would consider this function just as a shortcut for e.g. '=IF(OR(A1=TRUE,A1=FALSE),...' you would use =IF(ISLOGICAL(A1),...

Answer (score 0):

I am some years late in coming to the party, but couldn't you just have put

```
=COUNTIF(A1,B1&C1)=1
```

[image]