# How to evaluate a formula in Excel cell

Tags: excel, multiplication, excel-2016

I have an excel file which has some multiplication *(not the result but the formula)*
How can I find the result of each, if even possible?

**Excel:**

```
5*10
5*3*1
10
20*3*2
```

**Expected output:**

```
50
15
10
120
```

Here is what I tried:

```
=MID(A1; 1; FIND("*"; A1) - 1) * MID(A1; FIND("*"; A1) + 1; LEN(A1) - FIND("*"; A1))
```

This formula is okay for multiplications such as `5*3` but not for the others. I want to accommodate all 3 possible kind of cells.

Comment: Put an **=** sign infront of them

Comment: @Zac I cannot possibly put `=` sign in front of them. I have hundreds of thousands..

Comment: As Zac stated, put an `=` sign in front of them, but, autofill the `=` sign in a secondary column as `'=`. After this, `CONCATENATE` the two columns. Copy all the Concatenation Column, then paste the values...

Comment: Out of interest ,there is a method described [here](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-factor-12-secret-evaluate-function) that uses Excel 4.0 EVALUATE that still works. (It requires a named range, it doesn't work directly in a cell.)

Comment: @AndyG that is the method I point out in my comment below...

Comment: @SolarMike.  Plenty of links to follow to find the final `EVALUATE` answer, so:  with cell `B1` selected add this named range:  `=EVALUATE(Sheet1!A1)`.  In cell B1 add the named range `=MyEvalFormula` and drag down.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I found the udf easier...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in my Column, put an `=` sign in front of them, then, auto-fill the `=` sign in a secondary column as `'=`.

After this, `CONCATENATE` the two columns.

Copy all the Concatenation Column, then paste the values...

Results are as following:

[image]

Comment: explained well, so plus one from me, but this may be interesting : https://stackoverflow.com/q/53315486/4961700

Answer (score 0):

Part of it has been described in the comments and in the other answer, but the critical step is missing.

1) concatenate with `=`
 2) copy / paste-as-values the result in a different column
 3) Select that column, and go to `DATA > Data Tools - Text to Columns`, and click `Finish` (you do not have to complete any of the options, the default settings should work)