# convert a string sum to sum number in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I want to sum values of string cells. This idea is to convert the string cell to a sum number, then calculate the sum.
Here is an example to illustrate what i mean:

Let A a cell such that A="4+5+6", i want to convert that cell to a sum number as follows: A=4+5+6, than calculate A=15.

Long story short, is there a method/idea to convert a string sum to a sum number directly through excel.

Comment: Have a look at this q and its answers : https://stackoverflow.com/q/53315486/4961700  if useful give it a vote...

Comment: Search again for *evaluate* and *named range*.

Comment: You need `VBA`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

Excel VBA >> new module >> apply your custom function to desired cell.

here is the custom function

```
Function func(arg)
    func = Evaluate(arg.value)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming your text cell is named textcell you could use the following code

```
Dim arrayofWords
Dim sum As Integer
arrayofWords = Split([textcell], "+")
For i = LBound(arrayofWords) To UBound(arrayofWords)
    sum = sum + CInt(arrayofWords(i))
Next
MsgBox sum
```

Answer (score 0):

VBA Not required (SORT OF)

Evaluate is a bit of built in VBA script that does exactly what you are describing.  You do not however need to use the VBA editor.  Instead you can reference through NAME FORMULA.  However once you reference it this way, you will no longer be able tosave your spreadsheet as an xlsx format, instead you will need to use xlsm.

Lets assume you have your data layed out as in this image and you want the answer to appear in F10 and J12:

[image: setup]

## Step 1

Select the cell where you want the calculation to be performed (aka the cell where you want the answer to appear).  Doing this first will set the reference point for the following steps.  In this case I select cell F10.

## Step 2

With cell F10 selected go to the Formulas tab of the ribbon and then select Define Name  from the Defined Names sections:

[image: Ribbon selection]

## Step 3

In the window that pops up enter a name in the name box.  This name is what you will be using in your excel formulas.  For this example I chose the name "Answer".  In the refers to: box enter the following formula :

```
=evaluate(F9)
```

Note that there are no reference lock on the cell ($).  This make the reference relative to the selected cell in step 1.  In this case cell F9 is the cell directly above where the answer is supposed to appear in F10.

Select OK and the window will close

[image: Defined Name]

## Step 4

Now in cell F9 and in cell J12 enter the following formula

```
=Answer
```

Note that the same formula in two different locations evaluates the string operation above the cell and correctly returns two different answers.

[image: POC]

As long as the string is built of acceptable math operator that excel recognizes and there are no errors such as missing brackets, evaluate will process the string and spit out a value.  One problem I noticed back in the day was the named formula was only specific to the sheet it was defined on.  Each subsequent sheet required its own defined name.

Answer (score 0):

Without VBA:

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,CHAR(34),""),"+",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999)),"")
```

and copy across  *(this formula decomposes the string into its numeric elements)* . Then in **A2** enter:

```
=SUM(1:1)
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To avoid using "helper" cells, you can use this **array formula** in cell **B1**:

```
=SUM((TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(34),""),"+",REPT(" ",255)),1+(ROW(A1:A999)-1)*255,255)) & "0")/10)
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.