# Can I create an equation based on user-entered formula in a userform?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am creating a user form in Excel where the user needs to enter first the parameters necessary for the calculations I coded beforehand. However, there will be calculations that are user-specific. The calculations will require the same parameters the user entered so I can just use the text box name as reference but I can't seem to think of a code that will recognize that the formula entered is the equation it will use.

My end-users are broad so as much as possible, I am creating an excel file that is as generic as possible I could get. Majority of the calculations are generic to all users so I can code it before they use it.

I haven't tried anything yet since I have no idea yet how to create the code to solve my problem.

Comment: Well, you should do some searching on here - many ideas around you could employ... Saying that you may want to look at th answers to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/53315486/4961700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. bring the formula in as a `String`
2. insert a leading "="
3. change parameters as necessary
4. either `Evaluate()` the formula and use the result or
5. place the formula in a cell

   ```
   Sub UserSuppliedEquation()
   Dim v As Variant, sForm As String

   sForm = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Formula without leading equal sign", Type:=2)
   sForm = "=" & sForm

   v = Evaluate(sForm)
   MsgBox v & vbCrLf & sForm
   Range("B9").Formula = sForm
   End Sub
   ```

[image]