# String expression calculation in excel

Tags: excel, vba, string, expression, formula

I have lines with expressions such as  `8,753 - 1,087*4 + 0,1784*5*5 + 0,3447*4*4` in column A

I would like to have VBA calculate resulting value in column B.

Can anyone recommend something?

I tried the VBA evaluate function, but results in error, I tried indirect in excel, and I tried to insert a "=" in VBA - does not help either. Currently, only manually going to the cell and entering = to each line works, but I have 20000 lines like this and cannot change the input source or format.  There must be a better way to do this...

Comment: You might find this interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53315486/4961700

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string holds a valid calculation, `Application.Evaluate` will work. However, VBA assumes that numbers are using a decimal point, not a comma (comma is interpreted as parameter separator) - this is the reason you get an Error 2015.

So maybe use a function like this:

```
Function CalculateFormula(ByVal f As String) 
    f = Replace(f, ",", ".")
    CalculateFormula = Application.Evaluate(f)
End Function
```

Comment: This worked - the issue was with the coma / decimal - many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Without VBA:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=EVAL(A1)
```

Where `EVAL()` is a named function which refers to:

```
=LAMBDA(x,EVALUATE(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You must loop through each row in column A using VBA, evaluate each row's expression, and then enter the result in column B. To help you, consider this example:

```
Sub Values()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim formula As String
    Dim result As Variant
    
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
    For i = 1 To lastRow 
        formula = Range("A" & i).Value 
        result = Evaluate(formula) 
        Range("B" & i).Value = result 
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Public Sub test()

    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
    
    'Refer to the specific worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Get last row of column A
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        'Loop all values
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            'Replace extra spaces with nothing, replace "," with "." and evaluate the formula
            .Range("B" & i).Value = Evaluate(Replace(Replace(.Range("A" & i).Value, ",", "."), " ", ""))
        Next i
        
    End With
    
    
End Sub
```